# Does a capistrano rollback undo migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano

I'm new to this. I have a production server and need to deploy the latest version of the application from github, so I'm using Capistrano.

The newest release makes some changes to the database and hence has a bunch of migrations, so I'll be deploying it with deploy:migrate.

So my question was, if I add some data to the new columns created (it doesn't change any of the existing columns in the tables, just creates new tables and columns) and then want to rollback, then will cap deploy:rollback reverse all the migrations as well? Is the data in those new columns erased and the database back to the previous state (assuming I didn't make any data change except to the new additions in the db)?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801965/usefulness-of-db-migrations-rollback), where the gist is that rollbacks are fine during development, but not good after your code has been commited/shared or deployed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it will not.  You would need to manually run the down part of those migrations via rake and then roll back.

However, if your current app won't be affected by the new rows it won't hurt anything.

Comment: Ok, they've all been written using the change method, so I'll have to do rake db:rollback manually for the number of migrations I want to rollback and once they're all down I'll do the deploy:rollback?

Comment: @Achint rake db:migrate:down VERSION=xxxx.  There may be a way to do them all at once, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Right, I could probably give the number of steps or the version. So after I revert to the previous version, then running the deploy:rollback will essentially rollback the actual code and symlink to the previous release?

Comment: @Achint That's right. That's really all deploy:rollback does unless you have additional hooks in place.